# Troubles with splitting and parsing arguments to the main() method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having difficulties with the output from the main method. If a used enters a bunch of random Strings, my program should get only integers and group them as a pair. For example, if a user enters `3 2 54 -5`, the output should be:

```
(3,2)
(54,-5)
```

Or, another example: if the input is `1 2 3`, the program should output only

`(1,2)`

because there would not be any other pair found for number `3`. The main point of the program is to gather numbers into pairs. Exception is thrown if the program cannot convert a String into int. Could smb please help me out?

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception 
    {
        int [] number =  new int [args.length];
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            {

                number[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                System.out.println("("+i+","));

            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think, you need regex to get this output.

Comment: It does not make sense that the program is supposed to skip over Strings that are not ints, but at the same time it is supposed to throw an exception in those instances?  It needs to do one or the other.

Comment: You're right, @GregoryBasior. That's why I have to add an Exception. But to pass all of the test cases, the input would be smth like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 or 23 412 -33 2 2 0 2, or 1 2 3, or 2 2 2 2. The main point is I'm having trouble to gather the input numbers as pairs.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's good practice to .trim() user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is use the split method from the String class if you already know that the user will use that format, you cannot parse them because the user entered some spaces. If the data the user entered comes in the String array you can use something like:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception 
{
   int[] numbers = new int[args.length];
   try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i+=2)
        {

            number[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(args[i-1].split(" ")[0];
            number[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i].split(" ")[0];
            System.out.println("("+number[i-1]+","+number[i]+")");
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also if you use the i+=2, as you can see in the for, then you start in 1 and it goes up 2 by 2. Then it works with itself and the previous number, guaranteeing that there will only be pairs

Comment: Thanks, but what is the [0] for in two lines in the very end? It might give an error

Comment: the split() method returns an array that literally splits the String by the parameter you give to it and gives you an array with the values before and after the parameter, assuming that each [i] in args array has an int that ends in a space (given that your user puts it like that) you have to retrieve the first position of the array. You could also use the trim method that @Petro mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to loop through all of the inputs and not leave the loop the first time that a non-integer is hit, the try/catch block has to be inside of the for loop.  Then, in order to take care of the fact that you want pairs of ints, you do not want to print out every time that you go through with an int, you want to print out only when a counter that starts at zero is odd.  The counter is only incremented if an integer is found (when no exception is thrown).  Finally, I believe that what you are saying is that you want to throw an exception only if no int pair is found, so this would be the case that the counter never passed one.  So all of this can be handled as follows:

```
int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            {

                try
                {
                    number[count] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                    if(count%2==1)
                        System.out.println("("+number[count-1]+","+number[count]+")");
                    count++;
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    //if you're intention is to throw an exception if something other than an int is entered.
                    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
        if(count <= 1) throw new Exception("No int pair found");
```

Comment: thank you for the try, but it immediately throwing an Exception

Comment: @joshua, when I ran this code, I did not get any kind of exception, can you elaborate on the exception that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This'll work for you,

```
int[] number = new int[args.length];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(args[i]);
            if (m.find()) {
                number[i] = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
                System.out.print(number[i] + ",");
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```